# Speed of jQuery selector seems to be wrong my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I was working on optimizing some code where I need to disable the first option in my dropdown select menus. There are three methods I was comparing to find the fastest one, all can be found here [jquery-fastest-method-find-descendents](http://aahacreative.com/2010/07/19/jquery-fastest-method-find-descendents/)

They are:

```
1. Scope:  $(".child", $("#parent"));
2. Find: $("#parent").find(".child"); 
3. 'Normal': $("#parent .child"); 
(I call it 'Normal' because that's the one I normally use for everything)
```

According to the linked article as well as other SO posts I have seen both 1 and 2 should be the same, then 3 should be the slowest. However, I rigged up a little timing fiddle and it appears to be showing the exact opposite.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shewhqc4/)

For each of the three tests the fiddle create 1000 select menus, gives them 10 options each, and gives random select menus the disable me class (I wanted some variety to see if it changed the results). Then the timer begins, the jquery selector goes in and finds .disableMe and disables the first option.

So can anyone tell me why am I seeing the opposite results of what I am expecting? Did I mess up something in the timing part of the tests or maybe some high level logic got confused?

Code for those who dont want fiddle:

```
function createMenus()
{
    $('body').empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
         var select = $(document.createElement('select')).appendTo($('body'));
         if( Math.round(Math.random() * 1))
               select.addClass("disableMe");
         for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
         {   
             $(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).html('optionText');
         }
    }
}

//.find()
createMenus();
var start= Date.now();
$('.disableMe').find('option:nth-child(1)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
var diff = Date.now() - start;
console.log("Find: "+ diff )

//Normal selector
createMenus();
start= Date.now();
$('.disableMe option:nth-child(1)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
diff = Date.now() - start;
console.log("'Normal': "+ diff )

//Scope selector
createMenus();
start= Date.now();
$('option:nth-child(1)', '.disableMe').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
diff = Date.now() - start;
console.log("Scope: "+ diff )
```

Average results I'm seeing:

```
 Find: 20
 'Normal': 4
 Scope: 16
```

Comment: As a side note, this seems like it would be a _"micro"_ optimization as I doubt you have 1000 select menus on your screen. You may find this [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil#answer-80092) answer of interest as it discusses the problems that can arise with this level of optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is very subjective. selector speed optimisation is heavily browser dependent. the post you are quoting is from a time when IE7/8 were still relevant. potentially even IE6 was relevant to some people.

The differences are several:

1. browser does not have `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` - then the expression is parsed and broken down to bits that work, such as `document.getElementById`, `document.getElementsByClassName` (if available), `document.getElementsByTagName`- then appropriate filters are applied, such as pick only the nth type result etc. this will often involve multiple regex and function calls.
2. browser does have `querySelectorAll` - which has been heavily optimised by all evergreen vendors. given that the expression does not have any pseudo expressions like `:is` or `:not` or `:has`, it will be a straight forward pass through.

you can test this on your fiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/shewhqc4/show/light/

open the console and use:

```
console.time('select');
console.log($$('.disableMe option:nth-child(1)'));
console.timeEnd('select');

console.time('selectJQ');
console.log($('.disableMe option:nth-child(1)'));
console.timeEnd('selectJQ');
```

first one is QSA, second is jQuery - slower by some 8-9ms on my FF.

the reason why the other methods will be slower on evergreen browsers is because they are not the most common usecase codepath (first) and second, they need to `chain` results and pass context so more function calls.

ultimately, selector speed is a pointless measure as it's rare to have to continuously search the whole dom w/o caching results and unless you are writing a game, the gains will be meaningless.

Comment: That makes to me, didn't realize the article was so old. Thought I'd seen some newer references saying the same but perhaps not. 
I expected the gains to be more significant at first but then it became more of an experiment as to why this was happening, I'm not actually going to go back and refactor for these minimal gains.

Answer (score 2):

The article assumes that jQuery has to use the Sizzle library to parse and execute the selector. That is no longer true in modern browsers.

Most selectors (except the ones using jQuery extensions) can be executed using the `querySelectorAll` method. As this is built into the browser, it's faster than the first two alternatives.

The `querySelectorAll` method is supported in the current version of all common browsers, and as far back as IE 9.

Unless you have any actual performance problems, you should just go with the simplest solution. The advice in the article is a good example of how micro-optimising the code can backfire when browser implementations change.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Chrome's `Developer Tools` and in the `Profiles` menu collect a new `JavaScript CPU Profile`. After collecting the data, click on `Heavy (Bottom Up)` and change it to `Chart`, then you will easily know whats consuming more time.